# NetlifyCMS Auth on AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, bitbucket, gatsby, aws-amplify, netlify-cms

Has anyone used AWS amplify to host their static Gatsby site with NetlifyCMS? I can't figure out how to properly do authentication (using bitbucket). Do I need another package?

Comment: You can't use NetlifyCMS without hosting your own Authentication API using Bitbucket. You can inquire at the community chat https://gitter.im/netlify/NetlifyCMS